# Poner el menú lateral por debajo de la actionbar en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Como puedo poner un menú de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El que tengo actualmente esta asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se como hacer para que se quede debajo de la barra de navegación

Comment: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/09/aplicacion-android-con-navigation-drawer-y-tabs/

Comment: Gracias @dddenis

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta te va perfecta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34768685/1468942

Comment: Gracias Miquel, ahora lo pruebo @MiquelColl

Comment: @AlbertoMier he agregado un tutorial/ejemplo si tienes alguna para implementar, la comentas para que te ayudemos.

Comment: la barra de navegación es otra cosa, quieres referirte a la actionbar o la toolbar superior de la app, mirate mi respuesta a ver si es lo que quieres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres eso, establecer el menú lateral por debajo de la actionbar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Partiendo de lo que genera Android Studio 2.0 usando su plantilla Drawer Activity

Primero eliminar o desactivar que se solape con la barra de estado, quitar del `values-21/styles.xml` la directiva `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds`

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

y respectivamente en los layouts donde este `fitsSystemWindows` eliminar o bien ponerles valor `false`

El menú lateral está dentro de una vista `NavigationView` poniendole un margen superior bajarás el menú lateral. `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Te dejo los layouts de prueba enteros:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.testdrawermenu.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**values-21/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
            <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Es justo lo que queria @Webserveis

Answer (score 2):

Esta pregunta es popular, lo que deseas es agregar un `ExpandableListView` con uno o varios grupos en un `DrawerLayout`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te agrego un ejemplo de como construirlo.

Primeramente crea el layout principal `activity_main.xml` :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Agregando dentro del `NavigationDrawer` el `ExpandableListView` dentro del layout se pueden configurar los grupos, o grupo como se muestra en la imágen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora procedemos a configurarlo desde la Activity, se agregan comentarios en el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapterExpandable;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // obtiene el DrawerLayout.
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // obtiene el listview.
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
        // prepara datos para Header y Listado en ExpandableListView.
        prepareListData();
        // configura Adapter.
        listAdapterExpandable = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // configura Adapter en ExpandableListView.
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapterExpandable);
        // Puedes expandir los grupos por default.
        int count = listAdapterExpandable.getGroupCount();
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            expListView.expandGroup(i);


    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Agrega Encabezados.
        listDataHeader.add("Lenguajes de Programación");
        listDataHeader.add("Tipos");
        listDataHeader.add("Paises");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> lenguajes = new ArrayList<String>();
        lenguajes.add("C++");
        lenguajes.add("Java");
        lenguajes.add("Ruby");
        lenguajes.add("Python");
        lenguajes.add("Swift");
        lenguajes.add("Objective C");
        lenguajes.add("C#");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> tipos = new ArrayList<String>();
        tipos.add("Desarrollo Mobil");
        tipos.add("Escritorio");
        tipos.add("Web");
        tipos.add("Juegos");
        tipos.add("Bases de Datos");
        tipos.add("Analisis de Datos");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> paises = new ArrayList<String>();
        paises.add("Rumania");
        paises.add("Ucrania");
        paises.add("México");
        paises.add("Grecia");
        paises.add("Holanda");
        paises.add("El Salvador");
        paises.add("Guatemala");
        paises.add("Canada");
        paises.add("Francia");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), lenguajes);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), tipos);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), paises);
    }

}
```

Vista personalizada para el grupo, `list_group.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#FF9900" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Vista personalizada para los elementos hijo del grupo, `list_item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

y nuestra clase personalizada `ExpandableListAdapter` que extiende de `BaseExpandableListAdapter` :

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> miListDataHeader; // Titulos en encabezados.
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> miListDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.miListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.miListDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.miListDataChild.get(this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.miListDataChild.get(this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.miListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```